# Changing a variable each time a program i run - Python

Tags: python, variables, user-interface

I have a program with a GUI and a scoreboard which runs Rock Paper Scissors, but each time the program is run the Wins, Draws and Loses count is set to zero. Is there any way i can stop the count being reset and continuously be added to?

At the start of the code:

```
    x = int(0)
    user = 0

    score = str(x)
    draws = str(x)
    loses = str(x)
```

But i dont want to set the variables to 0 every time the program is run

Comment: Serialisation is an option, see `pickle` module for example [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#example)

Comment: If you want to save variables across multiple runs of the program, you need to write the values to a file at the end of your program and read them in again at the beginning.

Comment: Don't restart the program every time you want to play one more round. Have the code to run a round in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will be zero because it is declared to be 0, so if you don't lose save them to a file then load at start up.

Example:

```
def save():
    f = open('lastgame','w')
    f.write(str(score)+','+str(draws)+','+str(loses))
    f.close()

def load():
    f = open('lastgame','r')
    score,draws,loses = f.read().split(',')
    f.close()
    return score,draws,loses
```

You can also use `sys.argv` so you input them at command line.

```
import sys
score = sys.argv[1]
draws = sys.argv[2]
loses = sys.argv[3]
```

Then running using `python file.py 6 10 5` will make you start with score = 6, draws = 10 and loses = 5. But if you call without those arguments you'll get a IndexError.

Comment: With the sys.argv, How do i implement it into the code because it always comes up with : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\----\-----\CODE\Rock Paper Scissors GUI.py", line 22, in <module>
    score = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range